# How to instantiate a class from one module in another via interface assembly?

Tags: c#, prism

I have two modules(A and B) and 'interface assembly' that holds interfaces of the model classes from both modules. Is it possible to instantiate a model class from 'Module A' in 'Module B' by using just an interface of that model class from the 'interface assembly', so I can just reference 'interface assembly' in Module B, without referencing 'Module A' directly in 'Module B'?

```
 public class ModuleA: IModule
    {
        IUnityContainer container;

        public InputOutputModule(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }
        public void Initialize()
        {
            container.RegisterType<IInputService, ConsoleInputService>();

        }
    }
```

and App.config:

```
     <module assemblyFile="ModuleA.dll" moduleType="MainModuleLibrary.ModuleA, MainModuleLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" moduleName="ModuleA" >
          <dependencies>
            <dependency moduleName="ModuleB" />
          </dependencies>
        </module>

<module assemblyFile="ModuleB.dll" moduleType="CalcCommandParsingLib.ModuleB, CalcCommandParsingLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" moduleName="ModuleB" />
```

Comment: You could dynamically load Module A at runtime but one way or another, Module A would need to be loaded in memory before an instance defined in that assembly can be instantiated.

Comment: Are you searching for [Unity Container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff647202.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, please see updated code. But 'ConsoleInputService' is in ModuleB

Comment: If `ConsoleInputService` is in `ModuleB`, it should be registered with the container _there_. `ModuleA` can then have it injected in any of its classes by use of the interface `IInputService`...

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking: No, this is not possible. You cannot instantiate an *interface*; you always instantiate classes *only*. Hence there *must* be a—direct or indirect, static or dynamic—reference to your 'Module B' in any case.

There is a multitude of practical options how to achieve what you want. A few examples:

- [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) and [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) — most sophisticated and architecturally cleanest;
- a simple 'Module X' approach, referencing both 'Module A' and 'Module B', instantiating a 'Module B'-class and passing to a 'Module A'-class;
- dynamic loading of 'Module B', e.g. identified by means of a configuration entry, and using [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) to dynamically instantiate the given class.